# Understand meaning of statement in code - activityCallback = (ToolbarListener) context

Tags: android-studio, interface, fragment

I am trying to understand the meaning of this line :

activityCallback = (ToolbarListener) context

under the expression -

---

```
public class ToolbarFragment extends Fragment implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {


    private static int seekValue = 10;
    private static EditText editText;

    ToolbarListener activityCallback;

    public interface ToolbarListener {

        public void onButtonClick (int position, String text);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {activityCallback = (ToolbarListener) context;}
            catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must implement ToolBarListener");
            }

    }
```

---

I understand that a reference to context (here Parent Activity) will be created and stored in the activitycallback variable using the above expression.

However, I am unable how to understand how is it possible to cast an interface object to an activity (here context).

I am able to understand the other code in full and my project is working. It is a project in which a parent activity is communicating with two fragments using a listener interface.

I have attached the java files of the whole project in case you may want to review the code.

Regards,
Ravi.

```
----ToolbarFragment.java-----
package com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class ToolbarFragment extends Fragment implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {


    private static int seekValue = 10;
    private static EditText editText;

    ToolbarListener activityCallback;

    public interface ToolbarListener {

        public void onButtonClick (int position, String text);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {activityCallback = (ToolbarListener) context;}
            catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must implement ToolBarListener");
            }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_fragment, container,false);

        editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final SeekBar seekBar = view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        final Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonClicked(v);
            }
        });



        return view;
    }

    private void buttonClicked(View v) {
        activityCallback.onButtonClick(seekValue, editText.getText().toString());
    }


    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        seekValue = progress;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
}

-----TextFragment.java----

package com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class TextFragment extends Fragment {

    private static TextView textView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_fragment, container, false);
        textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        return view;

    }

    public void changeTextProperties (int fontSize, String text) {
        textView.setTextSize(fontSize);
        textView.setText(text);

    }
}

----FragmentActivity.java----

package com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FragmentExampleActivity extends FragmentActivity
            implements ToolbarFragment.ToolbarListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_example);
    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClick(int fontSize, String text) {
        TextFragment textFragment = (TextFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.text_fragment);
        textFragment.changeTextProperties(fontSize, text);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be several different activities that could host this fragment in different circumstances. So, we make a rule: any activity that hosts this fragment must implement ToolbarListener. That interface defines the "contract" between the fragment and the activities that host it. In onAttach(), we validate that the context is an ToolbarListener, then go ahead and save the cast to ToolbarListener for later use.

As the activity implements ToolbarListener so the ToolbarListener will be Parent of the implemented Activity's object. Hence you can Type cast it.

Comment: @RaviAgrawal Actually In Case of Object typecasting,  the classes we need to typecast to other Class must be related by inheritence. As per my understanding, comparing properties is not the case .

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. This does clear up the confusion. Have a good day, Sir.

Comment: @RaviAgrawal Happy to help.